# how to call/return ajax success object out of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to retrieve attribute values, I'm setting ajax get to a variable. Console.log returns the ajax object but I'm unable to return the object in success.

I have tried:
`ajaxObj.d`
`ajaxObj.responseJSON.d`
`ajaxObj..new_SubType.Value`

I would like to retrieve specifically `var obj = JSON.parse(XmlHttpRequest.responseText).d;` out of getAccountDetails()

```
function getAccountDetails() {
var accountObject = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("parentcustomerid").getValue();
if ((accountObject != null)) {
    var accountObjectId = accountObject[0].id;
    var clientUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
    var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc"; //Xrm OData end-point
    var odataSetName = "AccountSet";
    odataSetName = encodeURIComponent(odataSetName);
    accountObjectId = encodeURIComponent(accountObjectId);
    var odataSelect = clientUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/" + odataSetName + "(guid'" + accountObjectId + "')";
    var ajaxObj =
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: odataSelect,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) { XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); },
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(XmlHttpRequest.responseText).d;
        },
        error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('OData Select Failed: ' + odataSelect); }
    });
console.log(ajaxObj);
}
}
```

I'm following dynamics sdk RESTjquerycontacteditor script from sdk 2015.  Currently working on crm online

Comment: Is it possible to have some console output on what "data" is ?

Comment: Well I'm fairly new to javascript but using console.log and firefox I was able to find the correct "names" of the object that I needed to call and after modifying the code I got the value I needed @DanielRosano

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
var resultContact = data.d;
```

with this:

```
var resultContact = JSON.parse(XmlHttpRequest.responseText).d;
```